# Create mysql trigger via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, mysqli

I'm executing the following in PHP5.3:

```
$sql = "
CREATE TRIGGER `_photo_fulltext_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `photo` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `_photo_fulltext` SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `id`=NEW.`id`;
CREATE TRIGGER `_photo_fulltext_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `photo` FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM `_photo_fulltext` WHERE `id`=OLD.`id`;

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `_photo_fulltext_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `photo`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `_photo_fulltext` WHERE `id`=NEW.`id`;
    INSERT INTO `_photo_fulltext` SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `id`=NEW.`id`;
  END;
|
DELIMITER ;
";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

The "photo_fulltext_update" trigger isn't getting created.  This statement does run (and creates all the triggers) in phpMyAdmin.  I've read online somewhere that the MySQL server doesn't support the DELIMITER statement at all, so I'm looking for a way to re-write this multi-step CREATE TRIGGER statement so that mysqli::multi_query can send it to MySQL.

Comment: The solution is to simply remove the "DELIMITER" statements and the trailing "|".  I guess MySQL and/or mysqli parses the trigger block correctly without them.

Answer (score 17):

While the `mysqli` doesn't to anything with `DELIMITER` in `multi-query` statements, it actually doesn't do anything with any delimiters at all in normal queries, so just shove your triggers in one by one:

```
$ cat i.php 
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'test', '', 'test');
$sql = "
CREATE TRIGGER `_foo_fulltext_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `foo`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `bar` WHERE `bar`=NEW.`bar`;
    INSERT INTO `bar` (bar) SELECT bar FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`=NEW.`bar`;
  END;
";
$mysqli->query($sql);
var_dump($mysqli->error);
$ php i.php 
string(0) ""
$ mysql
mysql> use test;

Database changed
mysql> show triggers\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Trigger: _foo_fulltext_update
               Event: UPDATE
               Table: foo
           Statement: BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `bar` WHERE `bar`=NEW.`bar`;
    INSERT INTO `bar` (bar) SELECT bar FROM `foo` WHERE `bar`=NEW.`bar`;
  END
              Timing: AFTER
             Created: NULL
            sql_mode: 
             Definer: root@localhost
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
  Database Collation: utf8_general_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I faced using `BEGIN` and `END` keywords in the latest version of MariaDB :(