# Where to place Database Event triggers in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, triggers

I am making a web app using PHP. I want to place event triggers on the database.

I have the triggers wriiten. I have no Idea where to place them so that it is executed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Aren't triggers independent of the software/language using the db?

Comment: @kingkero I have the triggers wriiten. I have no Idea where to place them so that it is executed.

Comment: Triggers belong in the DBMS. So, use phpmyadmin or whatever tool you use to administrate your database and define the triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger is written like you write normal sql queries.

For example :
[Create mysql trigger via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762880/create-mysql-trigger-via-php)

Where are you using it though?

Comment: yeah. But what are u doing with triggers? and how does its availability to all users affect you?