# How to create triggers in Codeigniter's migration library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Triggers creation are just not working, I tried everything I can think of, for instance, like that:

```
$this->db->query("DELIMITER //\r\n
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_post` BEFORE DELETE ON `posts`\r\n
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN\r\n
DELETE FROM page_content WHERE page_content.post_id = OLD.post_id;\r\n
END\r\n
//\r\n
DELIMITER ;");
```

And whatever I do, I have the feeling it won't create the trigger because Codeigniter create the SQL statement in only one line. Tried with and without the line breaks, still get this message:

Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER `delete_post` BEFORE DELETE ON `posts` FOR EAC' at line 1

DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER `delete_post` BEFORE DELETE ON `posts` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM page_content WHERE page_content.post_id = OLD.post_id; END // DELIMITER ;
```

In PHPMyAdmin, the trigger create works by the way, so the SQL is valid

Comment: takeout the delimiter part , mysql_ or mysqli_ functions should be able to execute the trigger without the delimiter.

Comment: I'll try it, because it is definitely a delimiter problem, it needs to be on its own line in my tests

Comment: yes give it a try you may also check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762880/create-mysql-trigger-via-php

Comment: Yep, you guys were right, I was searching google for codeigniter instead of php, since it was using the query method. It works now without the delimiter. You should copy-paste my code without the delimiters so I can accept your solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove the delimiter from the trigger while executing via PHP.
    mysql_ or mysqli_ functions should be able to execute the trigger without the 
    delimiter.

Here is how to do it.

```
$this->db->query("
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_post` BEFORE DELETE ON `posts`\r\n
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN\r\n
DELETE FROM page_content WHERE page_content.post_id = OLD.post_id;\r\n
END\r\n
//\r\n
");
```

Comment: Thanks Abhik! For other people who see this, it also works without the \r\n

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to fix your issue.

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TRIGGER `delete_post` BEFORE DELETE ON `posts` ".
"FOR EACH ROW BEGIN ".
"DELETE FROM page_content WHERE page_content.post_id = OLD.post_id; ".
"END ");
```

Just don't forget to put a single space just before the closing double quotes at every line.