# Unable to create trigger in PHP for mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a trigger into mySQL using PHP

```
mysqli_select_db($host, "game");
$sql = "CREATE TRIGGER test_seven BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('test')";
$query = $host->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
```

And it is not working even though I tried running it on phpMyAdmin and it worked.

EDIT: "This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet"
Is there a way of skipping the prepare statement then ?

Comment: I also faced the same issue , for procedures / tiggers, still dont know why it does not allow, but my guess is , its due to user rights, in phpmyadmin user has diffrent rights/ privelges and when you do some thing with code it has diffrent priveleges, even though the user are same. Not sure if its correct or not

Comment: "not working" means what? What error do you get? Are you even checking for mySQL errors in your PHP code? Does the user which PHP is logging in with have rights to do this?

Comment: @ADyson "This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet" Is there a way of skipping the prepare statement then ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762880/create-mysql-trigger-via-php

Comment: Don't execute it as prepared statement. This is an admins job, not a programmers. But apart from that, I doubt that the statement worked, like you say. Your trigger would create an infinite loop and is therefore not allowed. Your insert statement would fire the trigger, which would fire the trigger, which would fire the trigger...and so on.

Comment: Well I don't know what Db library you're using but I would think you can run a raw query instead of a prepared statement. Just make sure it's not open to SQL injections

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks ! It works now.

Comment: @fancyPants It worked after I bypassed the prepare statement and yes you are right, I was just trying to make a quick trigger so i can see if it can create it. I will not use it, i'm going to drop it. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the real problem was the fact that I was not supposed to use the `PDO::prepare` statement, if anyone else is having this issue use `PDO::exec`.